# Как проверить, вводимая буква совпадает ли с той, которая мне нужна

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int N, i, b, m;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        printf("Введите b: ");
        scanf("%s", &b);
        printf("Введите m: ");
        scanf("%d", &m);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if ((b = 'A') || (b = 'B') || (b = 'C') || (b = 'E') || (b = 'H') || (b = 'K') || (b = 'M') || (b = 'O') || (b = 'P') || (b = 'T') || (b = 'X') || (b = 'Y')) {
                printf("YES");
            }
            else {
                printf("NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я вводить могу любое число, букву, мне будет писать "YESYESYESYESYES". Как мне сделать, если я, допустим, в b ввожу Q, то он мне выдает "NONONONO"?

Comment: 1) Вот это вот `b = 'A'` в Си - присваивание. А сравнение выполняется через `==`: `b == 'A'`. 2) Вы вводите `b` как строку, хотя это целое число. А дальше пытаетесь сравнивать с символом. Это как-то совсем странно.

Comment: Спасибо, упустил этот момент. Вопрос решен. извините. Да, b заметил и исправил уже после написания вопроса)